# Centering acronyms list

Tags: glossaries, alignment, acronyms

I would like to center the acronyms list for a page to be left aligned in the center of the page, however, they are currently left-aligned at the left end of the page.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[acronym, toc, nopostdot]{glossaries}

% Define acronyms
\makeglossaries
\newacronym[plural=PDEs]{pde}{PDE}{partial differential equation}
\newacronym{dd}{DD}{domain decomposition}
\newacronym{bddc}{BDDC}{balancing domain decomposition by constraints}
\newacronym{feti}{FETI}{finite element tearing and interconnect}
\newacronym{feti-dp}{FETI-DP}{finite element tearing and interconnect dual-primal}
\newacronym[plural=FEMs]{fem}{FEM}{finite element method}
\newacronym{das-6}{DAS-6}{Distributed ASCII Supercomputer 6}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[title=Abbreviations, type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]

\textbf{Example Text Containing Abbreviations:} \gls{pde}, \gls{dd}, \gls{bddc}, \gls{feti}, \gls{feti-dp}, \gls{fem}, \gls{das-6}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the centered acronyms to be centered as shown in the example below, and ideally still using the `glossaries` package or something similar that supports the `glspl` and `gls` commands:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Will your acronym list span multiple pages or just a single page?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It will likely only be on a single page, though for generality, it would probably be useful for an answer to handle acronyms spanning multiple pages (though if this non-trivial, I don't think it's worth pursuing for this question).

Comment: You could wait a bit before accepting an answer in case you will get a more general one which works for multiple pages :)

Answer (score 1):

If your acronym list only spans a single page, you could wrap it into a minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[acronym, toc, nopostdot]{glossaries}

% Define acronyms
\makeglossaries
\newacronym[plural=PDEs]{pde}{PDE}{partial differential equation}
\newacronym{dd}{DD}{domain decomposition}
\newacronym{bddc}{BDDC}{balancing domain decomposition by constraints}
\newacronym{feti}{FETI}{finite element tearing and interconnect}
\newacronym{feti-dp}{FETI-DP}{finite element tearing and interconnect dual-primal}
\newacronym[plural=FEMs]{fem}{FEM}{finite element method}
\newacronym{das-6}{DAS-6}{Distributed ASCII Supercomputer 6}

\begin{document}

\section*{Abbreviations}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\printglossary[title=,type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\textbf{Example Text Containing Abbreviations:} \gls{pde}, \gls{dd}, \gls{bddc}, \gls{feti}, \gls{feti-dp}, \gls{fem}, \gls{das-6}

\end{document}
```

[image]